# If the roots of a cubic polynomial $\alpha x^3 + \beta x^2 -3x +1 = 0$ are in HP, then what can be the range of the first two coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, upper-lower-bounds

The distinct real numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ satisfying the cubic equation $\alpha x^3 + \beta x^2 -3x +1 = 0$ are in harmonic progression. What are the ranges (upper and lower bounds) of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Four possible values of the pair $\left(\alpha,\,\beta\right)$ are provided: $A\left(-1,\,3\right)$, $B\left(2,\,-1000\right)$, $C\left(2^{2011},\,-2^{2011}\right)$ and $\left(\sqrt 5,\,\sqrt 10\right)$. Which of the values can $\left(\alpha,\,\beta\right)$ take?

(Zero or more alternatives may be correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: that's the same as the reciprocals of the roots of $\,P(x)=\alpha x^3+\beta x^2 - 3x + 1 =0\,$ being in arithmetic progression. The reciprocals are the roots of $\,x^3 P(\frac{1}{x})=x^3-3x^2+\beta x + \alpha=0\,$, and they sum up to $\,3\,$ by Vieta's relations. Then one root must be $\;\cdots$

Comment: @KaranKaran You are right on the first part, my hint was that $1$ must be a root, so by direct substitution this means that $1-3+\beta+\alpha=0\,$ $\iff$ $\,\alpha+\beta=2\,$. The only option among those you listed which satisifies $\,\alpha+\beta=2\,$ would be **A** with $\alpha=-1\,$, $\beta=3$ but of course that gives a triple root $x_1=x_2=x_3=1\,$. The other options **B,C,D** do not give roots in harmonic progression, and **D** doesn't even have three real roots. Maybe I am misunderstanding the `what are the ranges (upper and lower bounds) of α and β` part.

Comment: The roots will satisfy the specified conditions if and only if
$$\alpha >-1,\;\;\;\;\beta<3,\;\;\;\;\alpha+\beta=2$$

Comment: @quasi, dxiv. Yes, you are correct. In options B and C, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ cannot _simultaneously_ take the given values, even though the values _individually_ are within the ranges. The options must be wrong. I will edit the question. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: I think the problem would be improved if better choices were offered. Here's how I would word it:
$$$$
Which of the following pairs (one or more) are possible for $(\alpha,\beta)$ 
$$(A)\;\;\left({\small{-\frac{1}{2}}},{\small{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)$$
$$(B)\;\;\;\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}},{\small{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)\;\;$$
$$(C)\;\;\;\left(-1,3\right)\;\;\;$$
$$\qquad\qquad(D)\;\;\;\left(1-\sqrt{3},1+\sqrt{3}\right)\;\,$$
$$\;\;\;(E)\;\;\;\left(-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3}\right)$$
The valid answers are $(B)$ and $(D)$.

Comment: @quasi Agreed, choices like yours would make more sense.